# Is there a way to consume a message from a RabbitMQ Topic asynchronously?

Tags: java, rabbitmq

I'm trying to send a message to a `RabbitMQ` topic and then run my class that receives messages. But I don't know why, my consumer only receives messages synchronously. I saw some examples on how to do that with a queue, but with a topic it seems to be a little different. Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong?

Here are my classes:

```
public class ReceiveLogsTopic {

    private static final String EXCHANGE_NAME = "topic_logs";
    private static String message;


    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        String message = getMessage("#");
        System.out.println(message);
    }

    public static String getMessage(String argv) throws Exception {
        ConnectionFactory factory = new ConnectionFactory();
        factory.setHost("localhost");
        Connection connection = factory.newConnection();

        Channel channel = connection.createChannel();

        channel.exchangeDeclare(EXCHANGE_NAME, "topic");
        String queueName = channel.queueDeclare().getQueue();

        channel.queueBind(queueName, EXCHANGE_NAME, argv);

        System.out.println(" [*] Waiting for messages. To exit press CTRL+C");


        DeliverCallback deliverCallback = (consumerTag, delivery) -> {
            message = new String(delivery.getBody(), "UTF-8");
            System.out.println(" [x] Received '" + delivery.getEnvelope().getRoutingKey() + "':'" + message + "'");
        };
        channel.basicConsume(queueName, true, deliverCallback, consumerTag -> {
        });

        EmitLogTopic.sendMessage();

        connection.close();

        return message;
    }
}
```

.

```
public class EmitLogTopic {

private static final String EXCHANGE_NAME = "topic_logs";

public static String sendMessage() throws Exception {
    ConnectionFactory factory = new ConnectionFactory();
    factory.setHost("localhost");
    try (Connection connection = factory.newConnection();
         Channel channel = connection.createChannel()) {

        channel.exchangeDeclare(EXCHANGE_NAME, "topic");

        String routingKey = getRouting();
        String message = getMessage();

        channel.basicPublish(EXCHANGE_NAME, routingKey, null, message.getBytes("UTF-8"));
        System.out.println(" [x] Sent '" + routingKey + "':'" + message + "'");
        return message;
    }
}

private static String getRouting() {
    return "anonymous.info";
}

private static String getMessage() {
        return "Hello World!";
}
```

}

Comment: It's not entirely clear what part of your code is running synchronously. Could you add a bit more detail with respect to what is occurring across the `ReceiveLogsTopic` class and the `EmitLogTopic` class?

Comment: @SeanMickey Well, this is the problem. When I execute getMessage, the class waits for a message to be sent. When the message is sent, DeliverCallBack lambda print the message.